# How to rank according to a distance in a shapefile using R?

Tags: shapefile, r

I would like some help on the theory behind this. I have done this in GRASS easily but doing it in R is not the same.

Here's the table with the info, there are more tables similar to that but refer to different types. If I get this then I will be able to do the others since it the logic is alike.

```
%%UPDATE%%
```

I want the region (buffer of 500) to be ranked with 0. the 500-1000 (buffer of 1000 from the wetlands), 5 and the 1000(rest of land-more than 1000m) with 10

```
   type      distances    ranking
               <500          0 
 wetlands      500-1000      5
               >1000         10
```

I have imported the shapefiles in R but I don't know what to do with the table?

EDIT(this is what i did so far)

```
coastline<-readShapeSpatial("shp")
wetlands<-readShapeSpatial("shp")
wetbuf<-gBuffer(wetlands,width=500,byid=T)
wetbuff<-gBuffer(wetlands,width=1000,byid=T)
wetbuf$val=0
wetbuff$val=5
coastline$val=10
```

Comment: I have to make a buffer for 500m and pass it the rank 0.Then 500 through 1000 and pass the rank 5 then 1000 and more and pass 10 . Wherever 10 means high suitability.The question is how do i do the following using R. Thanks for trying mate

Comment: @gsa, you are still being a bit unclear. Are you wanting to perform a distance analysis and then rank the distances? If so, you do not need to buffer you can just use gDistance in rgeos to derive the distances and then ifelse to classify the ranks. If you are wanting actual polygons to represent the ranks just use gBuffer and then gIntersects to merge the data. You can assign the ranks to the attribute table such: buf500$rank <- 0  note; use an assignment "<-" and not equals "=". As far as I can tell, based on your question, you are already there.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans, i want actual polygons to represent the ranks. do u think it is correct what i did?it seems so.the issue is that i want to clip the part of the buffer that falls on the sea. how do i perform clip in r?

Comment: if it is right can u propose a more professional way to do it than the one i did?

Comment: @Aaron if i understood correctly Jeffrey said that my version was correct.i just want a more professional way of it.Thats all for the moment.

Comment: @Aaron your answer is fine remove the "On hold" if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform the following actions:

1. Read shapefile
2. Create a function to reclassify your distance values
3. Apply the function and write to a new field in the attributes "rank"
4. Write the results to a new shapefile

Of course you could simplify this if you only needed to read the shapefile attributes and work entirely within a data frame.

```
library(rgdal)

# Read shapefile
shp = 'C:/path/to/your/shapefile.shp'
myshp = readOGR(shp, layer = basename(strsplit(shp, "\\.")[[1]])[1])

# Handle NA values in distance field--here I convert NA to 0
myshp[is.na(myshp$distances)] = 0

# Create a function to reclassify the values
reclass = function(x){
    ifelse(x < 500, 0,
    ifelse(x < 1000 & x >= 500, 5, 
    ifelse(x > 1000, 10, NA)))
}

# Add new field "rank" and apply reclass function based off "distances"
myshp$rank = as.numeric(lapply(myshp$distances, reclass))

## write out to a new shapefile
writeOGR(myshp, 'C:/path/to/out_workspace', "out_shapefile", driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

---

The script populates a new field "rank" by reclassifying the values in the "distances" field.

[image]

Comment: i have edited to the question what i did so far too. Feel free to tell me your opinion about it.Now i will study your answer which looks very promising though i was under the impression that reclass you can do only in raster data.

Comment: @Aaron, ifelse would be a much safer approach to reclassifying a field. Your syntax is an independent evaluation and if there is a condition on nested value(s) the results will be incorrect. Try something like: ifelse(x < 500, 0, ifelse( x < 1000 & x >= 500, 5, ifelse(x > 1000, 10, NA)))

Comment: What i should do when there isn't a column named distances but rather they are defined by the buffer i made like this situation.Much more complicated

Comment: That is something you should include in the attributes when you do the buffer operation.